# QString in Persian

Tags: c++, qt, text, decoding

I have given a Qt Project which needs to support Persian language.T he data is sent from a server and using the first line, I get a QByteArray and convert it to QString using the second line:

```
    QByteArray readData = socket->readAll();
    QString DataAsString = QTextCodec::codecForUtfText(readData)->toUnicode(readData);
```

When the data is sent is English, everything is fine, but when it is Persian, instead of

```
سلام
```

I get

```
Ø³Ù\u0084Ø§Ù\u0085
```

I mentioned the process so people wouldn't suggest methods to make a multi language app that uses .tr. It's all about text and decoding not those translation methods. My OS is Windows 8.1 (for the case you need to know it).

I get this hex Value when the server sends سلام

```
0008d8b3d984d8a7d985
```

By the way the server sends two extra bytes at the beginning for a reason I don't know. So I cut it off using:

```
DataAsString.remove(0,2);
```

after it's been converted to QString so the hex value has some extra at the begging.

Comment: Try `QString DataAsString = QString::fromUtf8(readData)` instead. `codecForUtfText` looks for a byte-order mark, doesn't find it and assumes Latin-1 encoding.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for the reply.I tried your code and it gave me "".Did you try that yourself?Please let me know.

Comment: Could you please post the value of `readData` as hexadecimal values?

Comment: Sure.If I'm correct using the below code it is possible to get Hex.
QString res = appTitle.toLatin1().toHex();
and the ouput is: 3f3f3f3f

Comment: I mean the actual content of __readData__ as hex (that, what you get as a result of _socket->readAll();_) and put it in your question by editing it. Also, please use _@_ and my username when you reply to me, otherwise I won’t see that you have replied.

Comment: @scopchanov I've put the text "سلام" into Notepad++ based on the fact that my browser and Notepad++ support UTF-8 (or some other compatible Unicode encoding). The hexdump yields "d8 b3 d9 84 d8 a7 d9 85". (I wanted to copy the corresponding Latin-1 output also but Notepad++ died before I could complete.)

Comment: Please, use [`QByteArray::toHex()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toHex) to convert your `dataRead` to a hex-dump, print this, and add the outcome to your question (using [edit]). If it is the same I got in Notepad++ then your encoding is UTF-8. If it is something different somebody might be able to guess it from the numbers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was far to curious to wait for reply and toyed a bit on my own:

I copied the text `سلام` (in English: "Hello") and pasted it into Nodepad++ (which used UTF-8 encoding in my case). Then I switched to *View as Hex* and got:

[image: snapshot of Notepad++ - hex dump of "سلام"]

The ASCII dump on right side looks a bit similar to what OP got unexpectedly. This let me believe that the bytes in `readData` are encoded in UTF-8. Hence, I took the exposed hex-numbers and made a little sample code:

`testQPersian.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QByteArray readData = "\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85";
  QString textLatin1 = QString::fromLatin1(readData);
  QString textUtf8 = QString::fromUtf8(readData);
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWidget qWin;
  QGridLayout qGrid;
  qGrid.addWidget(new QLabel("Latin-1:"), 0, 0);
  qGrid.addWidget(new QLabel(textLatin1), 0, 1);
  qGrid.addWidget(new QLabel("UTF-8:"), 1, 0);
  qGrid.addWidget(new QLabel(textUtf8), 1, 1);
  qWin.setLayout(&qGrid);
  qWin.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

`testQPersian.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQPersian.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compiled and tested in [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQPersian.pro

$ make

$ ./testQPersian
```

[image: snapshot of testQPersian]

Again, the output as Latin-1 looks a bit similar to what OP got as well as what Notepad++ exposed.

The output as UTF-8 provides the expected text (as expected because I provided a proper UTF-8 encoding as input).

May be, it's a bit confusing that the ASCII/Latin-1 output vary. – There exists multiple character byte encodings which share the ASCII in the lower half (0 ... 127) but have different meanings of bytes in the upper half (128 ... 255). (Have a look at [ISO/IEC 8859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) to see what I mean. These have been introduced as localizations before Unicode became popular as the *final* solution of the localization problem.)

The Persian characters have surely all Unicode codepoints beyond 127. (Unicode shares the ASCII for the first 128 codepoints as well.) Such codepoints are encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as sequences of multiple bytes where each byte has the MSB (the most significant bit – Bit 7) set. Hence, if these bytes are (accidentally) interpreted with any ISO8859 encoding then the upper half becomes relevant. Thus, depending on the currently used  ISO8859 encoding, this may produce different glyphs.

---

Some continuation:

OP sent the following snapshot:

[image: Snapshot (provided by OP)]

So, it seems instead of

`d8 b3 d9 84 d8 a7 d9 85`

he got

`00 08 d8 b3 d9 84 d8 a7 d9 85`

A possible interpretation:

The server sends first a 16 bit length `00 08` – interpreted as [Big-Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) 16 bit integer: **8**, then **8** bytes encoded in UTF-8 (which look exactly like the one I got with playing above).
(AFAIK, it's not unusual to use Big-Endian for binary network protocols to prevent endianess issues if sender and receiver have natively different endianess.) Further reading e.g. here: [htons(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htons)

> On the i386 the host byte order is Least Significant Byte first, whereas the network byte order, as used on the Internet, is Most Significant Byte first.

---

OP claims that this protocol is used [DataOutput – writeUTF](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataOutput#writeUTF(java.lang.String)):

> Writes two bytes of length information to the output stream, followed by the modified UTF-8 representation of every character in the string s. If s is null, a NullPointerException is thrown. Each character in the string s is converted to a group of one, two, or three bytes, depending on the value of the character.

So, the decoding could look like this:

```
QByteArray readData("\x00\x08\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85", 10);
//QByteArray readData = socket->readAll();
unsigned length
  = ((uint8_t)readData[0] <<  8) + (uint8_t)readData[1];
QString text = QString::fromUtf8(dataRead.data() + 2, length);
```

1. The first two bytes are extracted from `readData` and combined to the `length` (decoding big-endian 16 bit integer).
2. The rest of `dataRead` is converted to `QString` providing the previously extracted `length`. Thereby, the first 2 length bytes of `readData` are skipped.

Comment: I used your code both it gives me empty "" but on UI and Consol.
       `QString textLatin1 = QString::fromLatin1(readData);`
        `QString textUtf8 = QString::fromUtf8(readData);`
        `qDebug() << textUtf8 << "\n" << textLatin1;`
        `emit(MessageSent("Clint said: " + textLatin1 + "\n" + textUtf8));`

@ and new line doesn't work.

Comment: [image](https://image.ibb.co/dSHFv9/Capture.jpg)
[img](https://image.ibb.co/i5hjNp/Capture2.jpg)

Comment: @stevemoretz I made this as GUI application (with `QLabel`) knowing for sure that my Windows 10 console is not able to print UTF-8. (I struggled with this many times. Even explicitly setting it to UTF-8 just prints non-sense.) The GUI instead has fine support for Unicode. (MS uses UTF-16 internally.) If you want to print on Windows console, you have to set a code page which contains the needed glyphs and localize the `QString` respectively. If you are on Linux, it's probably much better. Even in cygwin, the xterm supports UTF-8, and console output of UTF-8 is fine.

Comment: @stevemoretz Could you reproduce the results with my code on your side as it is?

Comment: I am on windows.And just used qDebug for the purpose of demonstration this is a GUI app and on both pictures I put but consol and GUI result this is a QMessageBox I used here for example.But I still couldn't get the result you've got.

Comment: Yes but give me a few minutes this class I'm using extends from QThread and it's not able to produce GUI so I got to do some things to let it use your code.Thanks for helping.

Comment: @stevemoretz You said you got "". Did you recognize that your [img](https://image.ibb.co/i5hjNp/Capture2.jpg) shows a `00` byte as first (in the dumps below)? Even for UTF-8, `0x00` (aka `'\0'`) is usually interpreted as string termination. (Just a guess.)

Comment: I guess that's what's wrong used your code it worked with your own readData but changed it to "\x0\x0\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85" and now it's empty.
I tried `readData.remove(0,2);`
but it doesn't work it's still empty. only deleting \x0\x0 manually on the code works.

Comment: @stevemoretz I just extended my answer with a possible explanation for this.

Comment: I can't vote up it says cause I'm new to this website I can't vote your answer up.

Comment: @stevemoretz You can accept it as answer (check mark). Your vote might be counted once you got enough reputation... :-)

Comment: I marked it as answer but I still don't know how to delete the first 2 bytes.Should I download this library #include <arpa/inet.h> isn't there an easier way.Which of those functions shall I use?and why didn't `readData.remove(0,2);` help!

Comment: @stevemoretz I'm a bit uncertain about _I tried `readData.remove(0,2);` but it doesn't work it's still empty._ May be, the length is encoded with 4 bytes and big-endian. In this case, it makes more sense to extract the first 4 bytes, swap it to native byte order, evaluate length and process a respective number of additional bytes as UTF-8 characters. Don't you have any doc. for the network protocol? (I hate reverse engineering without doc...)

Comment: Yes I actually do.It's here:
[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataOutput#writeUTF(java.lang.String)

Comment: @stevemoretz I believe there is no additional lib. necessary. Qt has sooo much stuff - e.g. [<QtEndian> - Endian Conversion Functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtendian.html).

Comment: I don't understand which function to use.I just modified your code to `QByteArray readData = "\x0\x0\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85";`
if it's a problem of yours too please give the function a try on your machine.I don't even know what to put T qFromBigEndian(T src) instead of T's on this template to get this working.the typedefs are a lot and I don't know which one is this case.

Comment: @stevemoretz I extended the answer a bit. And, I fixed a stupid bug of mine I found in testing... :-)

Comment: @stevemoretz My last sample code didn't work as the init. of `readData` ignored the other 11 characters after `\x00`... :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot but the last part still didn't solve it it gives "" still.Did you use it on your code did it work?I used it on your code but it didn't work.

Comment: @stevemoretz Now, I had a look into the link with protocol and adjusted the last part and sample code accordingly.

Comment: Great thank you very much Scheff that was awesome.And after talking this much I got the ability to vote up and voted that up.Have a nice day.

Comment: That is an excellent answer, @Scheff! Greethings from RP to BW!

Answer (score 0):

you need to send your data with utf8 like this

```
    mysocket->write(message.toUtf8());
```

and receive and convert to  utf8  like this:

```
    QByteArray Data = mysocket->readAll();
    QString DataAsString = QString::fromUtf8(Data);
```

your data will be sent without becoming unrecognizable

Comment: Hello Arash no the problem is server is on Android so you can't use this answer.Thanks for trying.