# Get unicode from lineEdit QT and write it to file

Tags: c++, qt

I have a code which has a `lineEdit` object.
This object gets into it a sentence in any language (not selectable which language) so it must support Unicode.
Then I have to take the Unicode out of it and write it into a file.

My problem is that `lineEdit` turns the text into plain ASCII and puts it into `QSring` before I can get to it so I get time and time again spam.

Here's a sample code of what I'm trying to do:

```
bool MainWindow::write_file(QString path, QString data)
{
    QFile file( path );
    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        QTextStream stream( &file );
        stream << data.toUtf8() << endl; // tried this -> didn't work...
        stream << data << endl;
    }else

    {
        return false;
    }

    file.close();
    return true;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    // ui->lineEdit->text bring to me the unicode into QString allready
    // how can encode the data to utf-8 BEFORE it get into QString?
    write_file(PYTHON_DB_COMMAND, ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

Comment: _lineEdit turns the text into plain ASCII_ That's not true! [`QLineEdit::text()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop) returns `QString`. [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details) (according to doc.): _The QString class provides a Unicode character string._

Comment: @Scheff i gett '??? ????' in QString , i assumed that the text change into plain ASCII and this is the reason for this. It drives me crazy because although it says that QString is supposed to support Unicode, all I get is question marks ...

Comment: I believe the error isn't in `QLineEdit`. Did you check in debugger whether `data` in `write_file()` is still correct - it should. About `QTextStream`, I'm not that sure - lack of experience. However, I found [`QTextStream::locale()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#locale) with the statement _The default locale is C._ May be, something to dig deeper... (For me, it sounds like the data gets broken in stream output but I'm not sure.)

Comment: Alternatively, you could write UTF-8 with a `std::ofstream`. This is what I usually do with success. (I usually test with `äöüß` which is on my German keyboard and generally good to uncover encoding issues soon.) ;-)

Comment: This was a somehow similar topic: [SO: QString in Persian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52025494/7478597) where I once answered, and there should be many more Q/As about encoding issues. What else? You could make a hex-dump of your output file and edit this into question together with original string copy/pasted from your `QTextLine`. Thus, community could be check whether file output is really wrong and how and, may be, even guess the wrong encoding. With this, it might be easier to find what is responsible for it.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up stuff.

Qt definitely supports Unicode; `QLineEdit::text()` returns a `QString`, which is a sequence of UTF-16 code units. What you are getting wrong is the IO part later; in particular, you are misusing `QTextStream`.

Let's put it aside for a moment. The easy way to write down UTF-8 content here would be just to open the `QFile` and straight write your string converted to UTF-8.

```
QFile file(path);
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    file.write(data.toUtf8());
    file.putchar('\n');
}
```

Straight `QFile` works just with byte sequences, what we put in it writes in the file (except for the idiotic newline translation in text mode, but I'm digressing); `data.toUtf8()` returns your string converted from UTF-16 to UTF-8, and that is written to file without much fuss.

What's the deal with `QTextStream` then? Well, `QTextStream`'s job is to provide helpers to write text-like content to files (in a way, `QTextStream` is to `QIODevice` what `std::ostream` is to `std::streambuf`<sup>1</sup>); as such, it provides methods to easily output `QString` values.

However, `QString` is made of UTF-16 code units, while the underlying file is byte-oriented, so a conversion is needed. To this effect, `QTextStream` uses an internal `QTextCodec`, which, if not explicitly set using [`setCodec`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setCodec-1), [is `QTextCodec::codecFromLocale()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#operator-lt-lt-12), which on Windows system is usually some legacy encoding (such as windows-1252), unable to represent most of Unicode; hence the question marks in your output.

Even using explicitly `QString::toUtf8()` and writing the result on the `QTextStream` won't help: as it is tailored to write *text*, it assumes the `QByteArray` you pass in is UTF-8 data, so [it converts it to a `QString` using its `fromUtf8` method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#operator-lt-lt-15), and then writes it (so, it gets converted with the aforementioned codec).

So, the correct way to go, if you want to write `QString` data to file in UTF-8 using a `QTextStream`, would be to first set its codec to UTF-8, and then straight output your `QString`s:

```
QFile file(path);
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QTextStream stream( &file );
    stream.setCodec("UTF-8");
    stream << data << endl;
}
```

Incidentally

- usually there's no need to use `endl` - besides outputting a newline, it also forces a file flush, which usually isn't something you actually need (and can kill the write performance if outputting many lines);
- you don't need to explicitly call `close()` on a `QFile` - it automatically gets closed on destruction (so, in this case, at the end of your method).

---

***Notes***

1. unfortunately this is not entirely true; `std::streambuf` is a three-headed monster, as it wraps the "associated character sequence" (=the underlying stream, such as an OS file) and a "controlled character sequence" (=buffering), in a similar fashion to `QFile`, but it also handles codepage conversion according to a `std::codecvt` locale facet, thus mixing up completely the semantics of the thing (is `std::streambuf` a byte sequence or a text characters sequence?) and complicating the implementation.

   As usual iostreams remains a great reference to how *not* to design an IO library.

Answer (score 1):

Set your [text stream encoding](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setCodec-1):

```
QTextStream stream(&file);
stream.setCodec("UTF-8");
stream << data << endl; // you do NOT need to convert .toUtf8()
```

Comment: If you set the codec correctly you should just output the `QString`, without converting it to UTF-8 by yourself. It does work, but you are converting back and forth for no reason: `operator<<(QTextStream &, const QByteArray &)` internally uses `QString::fromUtf8()` to get a `QString` to pass to the internal `QTextCodec`, which converts it back to UTF-8.

Comment: @MatteoItalia You're right. I stumbled upon that the other day when I wondered why QTextStream is so slow - if not used correctly, it converts between QString and QByteArray several times. Just didn't recall that when writing my answer.

Comment: There we go, +1 :-)

Answer (score -1):

in the call of write_file, add to the second parameter:
`.utf16()`  or `.Unicode()`
to get your `QString` converted to your Utf-representation.

I don't understand what you mean with "time and time again".

Comment: "time and time again" = over and over

Comment: what do you mean by `add to the second parameter: .utf16() or .Unicode()` ? QString is a unicode (according to doc.) ,Could you please add a code to explain what you meant?