# How to Convert Big/Little-Endian bytes to Integer and vice versa in C++

Tags: c++, qt, endianness

I'm going to receive length delimited frame from server with QTcpSocket in this format:-

```
+----------+--------------------------------+
| len: u32 |          frame payload         |
+----------+--------------------------------+
```

where u32 is in 32 bit unsigned integer encoded in Big-Endian format. depending on config, It can also be Little Endian But I will know about endianness beforehand on client side.

How can I convert first 4 bytes of this `char*` array or `QByteArray` to 32 bit unsigned int ?

After reading the frame I will need to send message in same format. So If I have message of length 20 bytes, How can I write 20 as 32 bit unsigned int to QByteArray or char* in Big/Little endian format ?

Comment: FYI: [SO: QString in Persian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52025494/7478597)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the way to do is:

```
bytearray -> stream ->setorder -> serialize to variable


QByteArray newData = ....;
QDataStream stream(newData);
stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian); // or BigEndian
stream >> variable;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Qt's [QtEndian](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtendian.html) utility functions to accomplish that.

For example, if you have a `quint32` (or `uint32_t`) and want to write that value in little-endian format to the first four bytes of a char array:

```
const quint32 myValue = 12345;
char frameBuffer[256];
qToLittleEndian(myValue, frameBuffer);
```

... or, alternatively, to read the first four bytes of a char array in as a little-endian `quint32` (or `uint32_t`):

```
const char frameBuffer[256] = {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
quint32 myValue = qFromLittleEndian<quint32>(frameBuffer);
```

Big-endian reads/writes work the same, just replace the substring `Little` with `Big` in the function-names.

Comment: Don't forget to include ```#include <QtEndian> ```